# can any one list all the valid arguments for setstyle() function for UIcomponents?

Tags: apache-flex, function, actionscript, arguments, flexbuilder

i am working with actionscript flex and using UIcomponents i need all the valid arguments for this function for example

```
component.setStyle("borderColor","white");
```

i need all valid strings for first string parameter and 2nd  valid argument for there value setting,

i have some of them that are given below but i need all possible values for this function

```
   inputs.setStyle("backgroundColor",0xA9C0E7);
   inputs.setStyle("borderColor",0x9E9FFF);
   inputs.setStyle("cornerRadius", 20);
```

thanx

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Locate reference for [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html)
- See "Styles" section.

Answer (score 0):

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#

Comment: To see attribute names, move sliders etc and they will appear on CSS Panel in right